# Android: шаринг в ВК

Tags: android, java

Всем привет.
Решил изучить шаринг в соц сетях, и начал с простого, через приложения самих соц сетей. Нашел статью про шаринг, и там приводился код. Я попробовал применить его относительно моего приложения, и при выборе из списка через что шарить (я выбирал VK) мне выдало сообщение "Отправка этого файла не поддерживается". Файл в jpg формате лежит в папке drawable. Скажите пожалуйста, как правильно написать.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/drawable/w_01_r_01");
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/jpg");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,  uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.app_name)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте немного по другому задать URI ресурса:

```
Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.drawable.w_01_r_01);
```